# Defining a metric on plane based on downward gravity force

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, physics, plane-curves, geodesic

What is the metric defined on $\mathbb {R}^2$ plane, where  downward gravity force ($\overrightarrow {-y}$ direction) causes the brachistochrone curves become its geodesics?

Comment: I don't know if this nicely written paper: Bernoullis-Light-Ray-Solution-of-the-Brachistochrone-Problem-Through-Hamiltons-Eyes.pdf that you can find on researchgate is relevant to your question...

Comment: What about [this one](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.26.825&rep=rep1&type=pdf) and [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.2055.pdf) ?